# .htaccess rewrite with sub directories not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite my url from:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?node=home&photoID=10
```

to:

```
http://mysite.com/home/10
```

Currently, for just

```
http://mysite.com/home
```

I use

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/?node=$1 [L]
```

however when I try to use

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

it doesn't seem to load my pages correctly, the pages aren't styled or anything.

(also, the top of my .htaccess file have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and if I just go to mysite.com/home it shows 404 not found. How would I do this if there is not always going to be a sub page?

Comment: What does your CSS inclusion look like? When dealing with virtual directory structures such as this, I find the need to provide an absolute URL to the path containing your stylesheets. The same goes for any other asset.

Comment: <link href="sitewide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> and my images and everything else just use regular links, not absolute URLs, which now would take forever to go back and do them all over.. But two lines in my htaccess i showed at the end fixed it for the regular one directory rewrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is to have your .htaccess rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then make sure to add this line on top of your page between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<base href="http://mysite.com/">
```

Comment: Thanks, though I haven't been able to get this to work as I want it :\ it keeps coming up with either errors, or the css/hrefs aren't correct because the css isn't been applied.

Comment: Can you post some 404 errors from your Apache's error.log file? That will help us determine what paths are not being found.

Comment: oh, thanks I never thought to check those, I think I've got it all figured out thanks to those logs.

Comment: `-MultiViews` turned out to be the key for me. Duh. >.> Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<base>` tag to let you relative URL's know where the URI base is. Since you've change the URI path from `/home` to `/home/10`, the base for relative links turns into `/home`. You need to add this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything except mess it up :\